# Get the memory address pointed to by a ctypes pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

Short version:
How can I get the address that a ctypes pointer points to?

Long version:
I have registered a python function as a callback with a C library. The C library expects function signature of `void (*p_func)(char stat, char * buf, short buf_len)` so I register an appropriate python function. When I get into the python function, I want to know the memory address pointed to by `buf`. How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you posted some source code using the {} tags. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for the "id" of the function http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id In [1]: a = 4 In [2]: id(a) Out[2]: 10019764

Comment: I am after the address of a bit of memory pointed to by a ctypes.POINTER object that has been passed to me by a c library, not the id of a purely python object.

Comment: I have fixed this myself with `ctypes.addressof(buf.contents)` but I can't answer my own question yet.

Comment: Gotcha! Matsalams!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have fixed this myself by reading the documentation.

I wanted to know the memory location of a block of memory allocated by a library. I had the ctypes pointer that pointed to said block. To get the memory address of the block I used `ctypes.addressof(p_block.contents)`.

The confusion arose around my understanding that `p_block.contents != p_block.contents`, but then I realised all `p_block.contents` objects have the same underlying buffer. The address of the underlying buffer is obtained with `ctypes.addressof`.

Comment: That's a bit like `&(*p)` in C where `p` is a pointer. What is strange is that ctypes does not define a `value` attribute for arbitrary pointer type as returned by `ctypes.POINTER` function. The `ctypes.c_void_p` class *does* have the `value` attribute, but the class returned by `ctypes.POINTER` does not. Very odd, counterintuitive, and almost reeks of incomplete implementation.

Comment: FYI https://bugs.python.org/issue26565, "Add value attribute to non basic pointers":

>> I know one can do addressof(p.contents), but it's a bit inconsistent that c_void_p and c_char_p contain the same information in the value attribute.

> The `value` of a c_char_p or c_wchar_p pointer is a Python bytes or str object. Since `value` won't consistently be the address value, it may be better to introduce a read-only `as_void` attribute that can be implemented consistently for all pointer types (including function pointers).

Comment: Gotcha! Hair pulling is over. Matsalams!

Answer (score 7):

```
real_adr = cast(anyctypespointer, c_void_p).value
```

Works for any kind of ctypes pointer - even function pointers etc. which lack `.content`