# Casting a c_char_p to a c_char array

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to access the contents of a char* by casting it to an array

Here's a demo:

```
from ctypes import *

foo = (c_char * 4)()
foo.value = "foo"
print foo.raw # => 'foo\x00'
foo_ptr = cast(foo, c_char_p)
print foo_ptr.value # => 'foo'
```

Now I want to convert foo_ptr back into a (c_char * 4). Neither of these work

```
foo_ = (c_char * 4)(foo_ptr)
foo_ = cast(foo_ptr, c_char * 4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it

```
foo_ = (c_char * 4).from_address(foo_ptr._get_buffer_value())

print foo_.raw # => 'foo\x00'
```

Comment: This may be old as `_get_buffer_value` doesn't seem to exist. Even if it did, the initial underscore suggests that it's an internal function. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784508/912144) is better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep the original *foo*?:

```
>>> foo = (c_char * 4)()
>>> foo_ptr_1 = ct.cast( foo, ct.c_char_p )
>>> foo_ptr_1
c_char_p(28211760)
>>> foo_ptr_2 = ct.cast( foo, ct.c_char_p )
>>> foo_ptr_2
c_char_p(28211760)
```

so the cast operation doesn't copy the data, but merely returns a pointer to the array's contents. You can also index through the pointer, although that's slightly unsafer.

Alternatively, if you want to create the array *de novo*, do the following:

```
>>> array_type = (c_char * 4 )
>>> foo = array_type.from_address( foo_ptr )
>>> foo.value
'abc'
```

Comment: It was just an example. In my actual code I don't have access to an array, just a pointer and length