# Pass ctypes structure to cython

Tags: python, pointers, cython, ctypes

I have a C library (called `clib` with header `clib.h`) that I call through `Ctypes`. A function `get_struct` returns a pointer to a structure `Foo` that is forward-declared  in `clib.h` and that I can use for other function calls as a pointer (like `use_struct(Foo* foo)`). I would like to use this pointer to call the same function code in `Cython`.

Since I do not know the content of the structure, I cannot create a duplicate structure in cython and copy over the values from the ctypes ones. So I would like instead to create a cython pointer to the same memory space in order to call some C code that binds the same API.

The code is roughly doing this.

In clib.h:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
Foo * get_struct();
void use_struct(Foo *)
```

On the python side with ctypes:

```
# load clib DLL
clib = ctypes.CDLL('clib.so')

# empty Ctypes declaration
class Foo_ct(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

# get and use the struct
clib.get_struct.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Foo_ct)
foo_ct = clib.get_struct()
clib.use_struct(foo_ct)

# call cython code
bar(foo_ct)
```

On the Cython side, in cylib.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "clib.h":
    cdef struct Foo:
        pass

    void use_struct(Foo *)


cpdef bar(foo_ct):

    cdef Foo* foo_cy
    foo_cy = <Foo*>&foo_ct  # or something equivalent
    cy_use_struct(foo_cy)
```

On the Cython side, in cylibc.cpp:

```
#import "clib.h"

void cy_use_struct(Foo * foo)
{
    use_struct(foo);
}
```

This does not build and returns errors either `Cannot take address of Python variable` or `assigning to 'PyObject *' (aka '_object *') from incompatible type 'void'` on the line `foo_cy = <Foo*>&foo_ct`.

Any ideas to go forward?

Comment: Since `foo_ct` is the address of a `Foo_ct` struct, you can do this `bar(size_t foo_ct):                                              
       cy_use_struct(<Foo*>foo_ct )`. That is, get the C object's address in python, and cast it back to C object in cython

Comment: it's a good idea, but this gives me a segmentation fault..

Comment: I can't test this currently so I'm posting as a comment: I think you do `ctypes.addressof(foo_ct)` to get the address. Cast that to a Cython integer then to the pointer. (I'm pretty sure the 2 step cast is necessary)

Comment: that seems to be doing the trick, this helped too:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687002/get-the-memory-address-pointed-to-by-a-ctypes-pointer

Comment: If you've got something that works then feel free to post it as an answer yourself (I'm not able to test anything well enough to write a good answer in the near future...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on @oz1 and @DavidW comments, the following works:

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
cdef uintptr_t adr = <uintptr_t>ctypes.addressof(foo_ct.contents)
cy_use_struct(<Foo*>adr)
```

Comment: A pointer as an integer is a `uintptr_t`, not a `long`. That would truncate the address on 64-bit Windows or any other 64-bit platform that has a 32-bit `long` type.